# What's wrong with this sed command?

Tags: sed

This command runs fine:

```
$ sed  -e '/foo/{g; d}' myfile
```

But this one has an error:

```
$ sed  -e '/foo/{g; a bar}' myfile
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: @TechZilla: I tried to write some composite command inside {}. Using `g;` is just some substitute.

Comment: In which manner do you mean composite command?

Comment: For example, can I do `{d;a bar}` if you think `{g;a bar}` is nonsensical.

Comment: they both are nonsensical, when you do `{g;` you are referring to spacing.  The second letter clarifies the changes.  What would the bar do?.  And if the `d;` does something, which it might, I'm not sure what it is.  But invoking anything in `{` is the very uncommon to say the least.  If you want to do any of the 'normal' uses of sed, like working with in regexp, you wouldn't use any `{}`

Comment: ... You meant like d\, for deleting a line, a\ add line?   I updated my answer.

Comment: @TechZilla the {...} is normal and is the mechanism to have multiple `sed` statements operating on the same address space, in this case /foo/.  So `/foo/{g;p}` means that on any line that that has /foo/ on it, replace the line with what is being "held" and then print it.  This could work for any address space: `1,/^$/{H;d};${p;g}` takes the first paragraph (`1,/^$/`) and moves it to the end of the file (`$`).

Comment: @Arcege: I understood how the curly brackets normally work, but the question was written in a manner where  they normally are not written.  I had trouble understanding what he was even trying to do.

Answer (score 9):

The `a` statement in `sed` requires a actual newline character (<kbd>Cntl-j</kbd>), not an embedded carriage return (<kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>).  So the only way to really get the `a` statement to work is:

```
sed '/foo/{g;a\
bar
}'
```

You need to have the newline after the line of input.  If you want more than one line, then quote the newline:

```
sed '/foo/{g;a\
bar\
xyzzy
}'
```

This goes back to the roots of `sed`, which is `ed`.

Comment: Your right, I pointed you.